# textview cannot be cast to org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView

Tags: android, casting, textview, android-mapview

I'm discover android programming and I'm facing following error : textview cannot be cast to org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView.

the following command is generating this error :

```
this.vuemap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.vuemap);
```

My mainscreen.xml is as follow :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trtext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#47FFFFFF"      
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50dp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#47000000" 
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50dp" >
    </TextView> 
    <org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/vuemap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView>


</RelativeLayout>`
```

What is quite strange is that if I invert textview/mapview position in the layout, there is no more problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/vuemap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trtext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#47FFFFFF"      
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50dp">
   </TextView>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#47000000" 
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50dp" >
   </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: It sounds funny, but I get similar problems after editting some of the xml files. The trick for me is to usually clean to force appt to rebuild the id tables. That might be happening indirectly when you invert the positions.

Comment: Hmmm... now I remember that I find this trick on stackoverflow : tried it and said : great : it works! then I revert to my original xml file (because I made lot of unuseful changes) and the problem come back and said : no, it was not that finally! :) At this time, the problem was random for me (I didn't noticed that the position change the behaviour). Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the project ("Project -> Clean") may solve casting errors for modified the xml layout file.
I think this action may also solve the problem if the text appear in another textview than the one it was supposed to appear.
Thanks to Greg!